# Updating libraries that aren't yet updated on pub

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I want to use an updated library (Vadim Tsushko's mongo_dart at https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart) but Pub (pub.dartlang.org) still has the older one, so a pub update doesn't help.  I replaced mongo_dart in my packages directory.  How can I update the package for all apps where it's referenced?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may temporarily change `pubspec.yaml` to redirect dependency from [pub.dartlang.org](http://pub.dartlang.org) to concrete GitHub repository. For `mongo_dart` it is:

```
mongo_dart:
  git: git://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart.git
```